# How do I like an item on a discussion board via REST or JSOM

Tags: rest, social, jsom

I have a discussion board with posts on it.

Discussion Board 1

post1

post2

post3

I want to "like" the item in post2 in "Discussion Board 1". How would I do this via REST or JSOM. I have looked into the [Social Feed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163237.aspx) and I can't understand how that works in relation to a specific list. It seems to pull back data based on a variety of information in the users profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use JSOM  to like an Item

```
 var  setLike = function (context, listId, itemId, isLike, likescount) {
            SP.SOD.executeFunc('reputation.js', 'Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation', function () {
                Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation.setLike(context, listId, itemId, isLike);
                context.executeQueryAsync(function () {

        }, function (sender, args) { console.error(args.get_message()) });
            });
            return false;
        };
```

isLike is a boolean value, you can get to know whether to like or unlike by

```
var getisLiked = function (likedby) {
        var isliked = false;
        if (likedby !== null && likedby !== undefined) {

            for (var i = 0; i < likedby.length; i++) {
                var like = likedby[i];
                if (like.get_lookupId() === _spPageContextInfo.userId) {
                    isliked = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        return isliked;
    };
```

likedBy is the Value of "LikedBy" column (internal name)

Comment: Where does reputation.js come from? I don't see that file anywhere on the SharePoint instance I am running on.

Comment: Also, where does the parameter "likedby" come form in the second method?

Comment: it comes from LikedBy(internalname) column of the list

Comment: use get_fieldValues() method on listitem to get the JSON response, you can see LikedBy there

Comment: reputation.js is  "/_layouts/15/reputation.js", if it not registerd by default on you masterpage, call RegisterSod('reputation.js','/_layouts/15/reputation.js'); at the top of your js

Comment: Couple more questions is the list id the guid of the list? How would I retrieve that and same for the itemID?

Comment: how are you displaying them on UI, not using JSOM?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27150/discussion-between-artfuldodger-and-sekhar).

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var followingEndpoint;
var URL;
var website;
var clientContext;

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', loadWebsite);

function loadWebsite() {
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    website = clientContext.get_web();
    clientContext.load(website);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        onRequestSucceeded,
        onRequestFailed);
}

function onRequestSucceeded() {
    URL = website.get_url();
    followingEndpoint = decodeURIComponent(URL) + "/_api/social.following";
    getFollowedDocs();
}

function onRequestFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
}

function getFollowedDocs() {
    $.ajax({
        url: followingEndpoint + "/my/Followed(types=2)",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: retrieveFollowedDocs,
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("GET error:\n" + xhr.status + "\n" + thrownError);
        }
    });
}

function retrieveFollowedDocs(data) {
    var stringData = JSON.stringify(data);
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(stringData);
    var followed = jsonObject.d.Followed.results;
    //var threads = followed.results;
    var followedContent = '';
    followedContent +='<table><thead><tr><th>Title</th></tr></thead></table><ul>';

  for (var i = 0; i < followed.length; i++)  {
        //The Below if condition is for the Document limit. I need 5 documents to be displayed so given i=5. Based on your requirement you can the number.
    if (i ==5)  {
        var qryString = window.location.href;
        var qrySplit = qryString.split('?');
        if (qrySplit.length > 1)  {
            continue;
        }
        else  {
            break;
        }
        }

        var folDocs = followed[i];
        var NamewithExtn = folDocs.Name;
        var docName = NamewithExtn.split('.');
        var Name = docName[0];
        var ContentURL = folDocs.Uri;
        followedContent += '<li>';
        followedContent += '<table><tbody><tr><td><a href="'+URL+'">'+Name+'</a>';
        followedContent += '</td></tr></tbody></table>';
        followedContent += '</li>'
    }
    followedContent +='</ul>';
    $("#message").empty();
    $("#message").append(followedContent);
    innerTable = '';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="message"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Put a link for discussion, so you can follow a document by configure MySites. In MySites there is Document Library created with all the followed documents.

Use above code if you want to display the liked messages.