# Like a list item function

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest, list-item, social

I'm trying to implement the standard like function to a custom view I wrote.

My code for getting the items, getting LikesCount and how I display them:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {    
    // Rest Call
    var requestUri = "/_api/lists/getbytitle('Shout')/items";

    var llength = "";

        $.ajax({
            url: requestUri,
            type: "GET",
            headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data.d.results, function (i, item){
                    var title = item.Title;
                    var description = item.Description;
                    var pictureURLDesc = item.PictureURL.Description;
                    var pictureURL = item.PictureURL.Url;   
                    var linkDesc = item.Link.Description;
                    var linkURL = item.Link.Url;    
                    var likesCount = item.LikesCount;               

                    try 
                    {
                        llength = description.slice(0, 120);
                    } 
                    catch ( err ) 
                    { 
                        alert( err ); 
                    }               

                    // alert("The item has " + likesCount + " likes");

                    // Set News item                        
                    document.getElementById("head" + i).innerHTML = "<div class='thumbnail-img'><div class='overflow-hidden'><img class='img-responsive' src=" + pictureURL + " alt=" + pictureURLDesc + "/> &#160;</div><a class='btn-more hover-effect' href='#'><i class='icon-thumbs-up'></i> " + likesCount + "</a></div><div class='caption'><h3><a class='hover-effect' href='#'>" + title + "</a></h3><p>" + llength + "</p></div>";

                })
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error getting items");
            }                     
        });    

});
```

The function is turned on in the list and I can rate / unrate the items there.

[image]

This is how it is displayed by now:

[image]

Now I want this functionality in my script. I found several posts how to like a page, but nothing which helps me to like a list item.

I would like to call the function in here:

```
<a class='btn-more hover-effect' href='#'>
```

I can get the current LikesCount with REST, but how to set and unset?

Any Step-by-Step guides known?

Comment: Perhaps this might help: http://sharepointclouds.blogspot.in/2014/12/like-and-unlike-update-list-item-using.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a similar Question and I answered there.
[Liking a discussion board list item](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153577/how-do-i-like-an-item-on-a-discussion-board-via-rest-or-jsom/)

We have an OOTB JS library "reputation.js". Load the Library and call the function
`Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation.setLike` to like/unlike a list item. 
Other source [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134497/enable-like-function-from-catalog-page-via-javascript-object-model-improve-thi). Do not forget to upvote Vadim Gremyachev's answer if helped.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a huge noob if it comes to implementing this into my code. I guess it is the right way, but could you help me there a little bit? That would be awesome!

Comment: I think you can understand better from this article. http://www.sharepointstuffs.com/using-like-and-rating-functionality-in-sharepoint-2013-pages/  .All we need is the list id and listitem id for setLike function. Ignore _spPageContextInfo.pageListId and _spPageContextInfo.pageItemId in this article and pass your list id and listitem id instead.

Comment: It is finally working... Thanks for your help. I will try to upload a blog post, how everthing worked out for me.

Comment: Also postet now my scripts and all I needed here: https://blog.afrait.com/like-a-list-item-facebook-like/

Comment: Great. I regularly follow this site,  Interesting , it is yours. :)

Comment: :D Small SharePoint world ;) Write me a email over my blogsite, so we can stay in touch and exchange more knowledge! That would be great!